# Tetrahedral Sums

Tags: number-theory, summation, proof-writing

The tetrahedral numbers can be interpreted as the sums of the triangular numbers, which are then sums of the natural numbers.

If I take `L` distinct tetrahedral numbers and sum them together to `n`, do any other `L` distinct tetrahedral numbers exist such that they also sum to `n`?

So far, I've represented these sums as follows:
(For example, when `L = 3`)

`(1) + (1+2) + (1+2+3) + (1+2+3+4)               | T1
+(1) + (1+2) + (1+2+3)                           | T2
+(1) + (1+2) + (1+2+3) + (1+2+3+4) + (1+2+3+4+5) | T3
= n`

It seems to me that the triangular number "blocks" of any `t` (denoted in parantheses) cannot be split up in a way to add on to another tetrahedral number without leaving some sort of remainder, voiding `t`'s property as tetrahedral.

Is this the right way to approach this problem? If so, how would I go on to write it formally in a proof-like fashion?

Thanks

EDIT: Rather than asking how many pairs of L-tuples exist that sum to the same arbitrary n, instead I'm asking: for a specific locked n, how many additional sets of length L of tetrahedral numbers exist such that they sum to n?

Is it really just pairs? Or do triplets exist? Etc.

Comment: Your question asks something different than the "seems to me" paragraph implies.  The question is about sets of $L$ tetrahedral numbers.  Tetrahedral numbers are of the form $\frac16(a)(a+1)(a+2)$ so for $L=2$ you are asking whether there are distinct $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ such that $a(a+1)(a+2) + b(b+1)(b+2) = c(c+1) (c+2) + d(d+1) d+2)$. Is this what you meant to ask?

Comment: For $L = 8$, there are infinitely many pairs of  $L$-tuple of tetrahedron numbers which sum to same number. In particular, $T_n$ satisfies
a recurrence relation of the form:
$$\begin{align} &\; T_{n+15}+T_{n+12}+T_{n+10}+T_{n+9}+T_{n+6}+T_{n+5}+T_{n+3}+T_n
\\
= &\;T_{n+14}+T_{n+13}+T_{n+11}+T_{n+8}+T_{n+7}+T_{n+4}+T_{n+2}+T_{n+1}\end{align}
$$

Comment: $T_1+T_2+T_3+T_4=1+ 4+ 10+ 20=35=T_5$

Comment: @Mark Fischler I clarified my question in the edit above. Please let me know if any confusion still exists

Comment: @Raffaele In that example, the lengths are different. L=4 and L=1. I'm asking for sums of an equal number or tetrahedral numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When $L$ is large enough ($L = 4$ or $\ge 6$), there will be infinitely many pairs of  $L$-tuple of tetrahedron numbers which sum to same number.

In particular, this happens at $L = 8$. $T_n$ satisfies a recurrence relation of the form:

$$\begin{align} &\; T_{n+15}+T_{n+12}+T_{n+10}+T_{n+9}+T_{n+6}+T_{n+5}+T_{n+3}+T_n
\\
= &\;T_{n+14}+T_{n+13}+T_{n+11}+T_{n+8}+T_{n+7}+T_{n+4}+T_{n+2}+T_{n+1}\end{align}
\tag{*1}
$$
The key is $\displaystyle\;T_n = \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}$ is a cubic polynomial in $n$.

Let $\ell = \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ be the space of real sequences indexed by natural numbers. Let $R : \ell \to \ell$ be the operator on $\ell$ which shift  a sequence to the right. More precisely, for any real sequence $a = (a_n)$, $R(a)$ is the sequence with entries $R(a)_n = a_{n+1}$. One property of $R$ is if $a_n$ is a polynomial in $n$ of degree $m$, then $(R-1)(a) = R(a) - a$ is a polynomial in $n$ of degree $m-1$.

Since $T_n$ is a polynomial in $n$ of degree $3$, we have

$$(R-1)^4(T) = R^4(T) - 4R^3(T) + 6R^2(T) - 4R(T) + T = 0$$

Equivalently, this means $T_n$ satisfies a recurrence relation of the from

$$T_{n+4} - 4T_{n+3} + 6T_{n+2} - 4T_{n+1} + T_n = 0$$

For any $L > 4$, if one can find a polynomial $q(x)$ with $2L$ non-zero terms, $L$ of which has coefficient $1$ and other $L$ has coefficient $-1$ and $(x-1)^4 | q(x)$, then one can turn it into recurrence relation like $(*1)$ for that particular $L$.

As an example, the recurrence relation in $(*1)$ is constructed using the polynomial
$$\begin{align}
q(x) = & (x^8-1)(x^4-1)(x^2-1)(x-1)\\
= &\;\;(x^{15}+x^{12}+x^{10}+x^9+x^6+x^5+x^3+1)\\
  &-(x^{14}+x^{13}+x^{11}+x^8+x^7+x^4+x^2+x)
\end{align}$$
I hope the pattern is obvious.

**Update**

It turns out for even $L$, $L = 4$ is large enough.

By trial and error, I obtain following recurrence relation:

$$T_{9k+8}+T_{8k+5}+T_{5k+3}+T_{4k+4}
= T_{9k+6}+T_{8k+7}+T_{5k+5}+T_{4k+3}$$

This implies there are infinite many pairs of $4$-tuples which sum to same number.

For $L = 6$, we can use $q(x) = (x^6-1)(x^4-1)(x^2-1)(x-1)$ to obtain another
recurrence relation:

$$\begin{align} &T_{n+13}+T_{n+10}+T_{n+8}+T_{n+5}+T_{n+3}+T_{n}\\
=\;\;&T_{n+12}+T_{n+11}+T_{n+9}+T_{n+4}+T_{n+2}+T_{n+1}\end{align}$$

This means same thing happens to $L = 6$.  Since every even integer $L \ge 4$ can be rewritten as a non-negative combination of $4$ and $6$. We can combine these two sets of recurrence relations to conclude whenever $L \ge 4$ is even, there are infinite many pairs of $L$-tuples which sum to same number.

**Update2**

By brute force, I have located a pair of $3$-tuple of tetrahedron numbers
which sums to same number.

$$T_{24}+T_{18}+T_{3} = 3750 = T_{19} + T_{23} + T_{8}$$

Since every odd $L \ge 7$ can be written as $3$ plus some non-trivial non-negative combinations of $4$ and $6$. It is easy to see for any odd $L \ge 7$, there are also infinitely many pairs of $L$-tuple which sum to same number.

The only thing we haven't settle is whether there are infinitely many pairs
of $L$-tuples for $L = 3$ and $5$.

**Update3**

About the corrected question whether there are triples, quadruples or even more
$L$-tuples that sum to same number. The answer is yes.

Consider the case $L = 3$, triples, quadruple and even quintuple are possible.
In fact, there are tons of them. By brute force, the smallest examples I can find are:

- *triple*
  $$n = 305 
      = T_{10}+T_7+T_1
      = T_9 + T_8 + T_4
      = T_9 + T_7 + T_6
  $$
- *quadruple*
  $$\begin{align}
  n = 1795 
    &= T_{21} + T_4 + T_2
    = T_{20}+T_{10}+T_5\\
    &= T_{19} + T_{13}+T_3
    = T_{17}+T_{16}+T_3
  \end{align}
  $$
- *quintuple*
  $$\begin{align}
  n = 2366 &= T_{23} + T_6 + T_3
            = T_{22} + T_{11} + T_6
             = T_{21} + T_{14} + T_5\\
           &= T_{20} + T_{16} + T_3
           = T_{19} + T_{16} + T_{10}
  \end{align}
  $$

I have no idea whether there are hextuples of $3$-tuples that sum to same number.
My CAS simply crash when I try to search for one by brute force.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer. However, I wasn't necessarily asking for how many pairs of tuples exist that sum to a number n, which is allowed to change and grow. Rather, I would like to know how many possible recurrence relations of length L exist for any one constant N, obtained from summing any L tetrahedral numbers. Is it just two, or do more exist? I will edit my question to clarify this. Thanks for your help

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you!